# Javascript TypeError where "options" argument must be of type object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import unoconv from 'unoconv';
import fs from 'fs';

unoconv.convert('./ExampleData.txt', 'pdf', function (err, result) {
  fs.writeFile('converted.pdf', result);
})
```

Why am I unable to return the result object and why does it throw the error?

Comment: I think the issue may be related to `unoconv` not liking the relative path. Try changing `./Cust....txt` to `Cust....txt` as `unoconv` assumes _CWD_.

Comment: What Node.js version do you use?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Tried it - same issue

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt v10.12.0

Answer (score 0):

If you use https://github.com/gfloyd/node-unoconv and if I understand the error stack correctly, the module is too old and is not compatible with supported Node.js versions.

See https://github.com/gfloyd/node-unoconv/blob/master/index.js#L46 which is not compatible with the last `childProcess.spawn()` signatures (the third argument should be Object).

Answer (score -1):

You're using ES5 and you are not using a `return` when you should be.  ES6+ has fat arrow functions `=>` which have implicit returns.
Either way, I find it's good convention to add the `return` if you break to a new line.

Comment: Not related to this issue. This is an API call related issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn they're asking "Why am I unable to return the result object", they're not actually returning anything but writing a file to disk.  The return would be a Buffer object.  So I assume you need a return statement in the function in order to access the Buffer.  Maybe I'm wrong.  But that's what I gathered from the sparse documentation of the package.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm reading the post title about the TypeError and the part of the question that says "_why does it throw the error_"